# Flash Builder 4.6 | Pie Chart not able to refresh

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, refresh, flash-builder, pie-chart

I’m having trouble getting my pie chart in Flash Builder 4.6 | Halo theme | mx:application to update properly. I’m working between two states.

**States**

- State 1 - has a dataGrid and ComboBoxes to filter the datagrid. Basically from the current datagrid view I’m storing 6 category totals to variables
- State 2 - I have a pie chart that is bound to an arrayCollection

**Setup**

- I have a global Bindable arrayCollection
- The pie chart is bound to that global arrayCollection
- I have a function that then creates the arrayCollection items (which include the category variables), then assigns it to the global arrayCollection.

**Problem**

- When state 2 initially loads, the pie chart pulls in the correct data. But when I go back to state 1, adjust the filters which update the category totals, then go back to state 2 the pie chart is keeping the original data and I need it to refresh.

**What I’ve noted/tested**

- I display the category total in other areas within state 2, so I know the totals are updating
- I placed the pie chart in state 1 (which has the filters) and whenever I adjusted the filters, then the pie graph updated correctly
- I’ve tired placing a button in state 2 to refresh the arrayCollection & refresh dataProvider of the chart

Here's some of the code tied to the pie chart.
Thanks in advance!

[The chartHandler is via creationComplete]

```
[Bindable] public var chartDataGlobal:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([]);

        protected function chartHandler():void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var chartData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
                { Category: "Clinical", Total: clinicalTotal},
                { Category: "Rehab", Total:  rehabTotal},
                { Category: "Healthcare", Total: healthcareTotal },
                { Category: "Textiles", Total: textilesTotal },
                { Category: "Foodservice", Total: foodServiceTotal },
                { Category: "Environmental", Total: environmentalTotal }]);

            chartDataGlobal=chartData;

        }

<mx:PieChart id="chart" includeIn="summary" x="-8" y="22" width="357" height="378"  paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" showDataTips="true" x.start="39" y.start="42"
                         height.summary="386" dataProvider="{chartDataGlobal}">          
                <mx:series>
                    <mx:PieSeries id="PieSeries" nameField="Category" field="Total">                    
                        <mx:filters>
                            <mx:DropShadowFilter />
                        </mx:filters>
                    </mx:PieSeries>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:PieChart>
```

Comment: As a work around, is there maybe a way to have the creationComplete like functionality to fire off every time I enter state 2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the pie chart nested inside a sGroup, then an HBox. After removing the chart and just placing it on the stage, it started pulling in the updated totals. I'm not exactly sure why this mattered, but it's now working.